# How do I find out what the latest version of a package is for a given version of RHEL?

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel6, package-management

When working with for instance Ubuntu, I'm used to being able to look up which version of a given package is available for a given version of Ubuntu Server on [launchpad.net/ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu).

Is there a similar resource for Red Hat Enterprise Linux?

I have non-`sudo` access to a server and so it seems I can't just use `yum` to check for updates (even without installing).

**Please note:** For security reasons won't be able to "just get sudo access". I can find out which version of a piece of software is *actually* installed but not if it's the newest (it seems).
Also: I'm using RHEL 6.6.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you run "yum search <packagename>" and "yum info <packagename>" with an unprivileged account?

Comment: @Andy: Good idea! However, running any of the 2 yields this message before listing anything: **Note* Red Hat Network repositories are not listed below. You must run this command as root to access RHN repositories.* So for non-Red Hat, it'd work but in my case was looking for OpenSSL which comes from the RH as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check latest source package versions on their public ftp server.

ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Server/en/os/SRPMS/